# Transparent Squid3, and how to make it pass requests through another proxies?

Tags: linux, squid

As I understand, my question is not about proxy hierarchies.

I was lucky enough to set up a Squid3 as a transparent proxy. It works good, and all requests go through it.

Now, a user on one of the computers in the network I supervise wanted to use his own proxy. He set up a browser settings to use *that* proxy. First the request goes through my transparent Squid, which is OK.

But then, surprisingly enough, my transparent Squid makes a request directly to the target server. It does not use *that* proxy one of users wished to use.

Is it a bug, a feature, or, I hope, I just did something wrong with the configuration file?
Please, if anyone has experience with that, give me some idea about that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand this is the flow of the data from the user's computer to the internet. If your squid is directly connecting to the target then it is the desired functionality.

The data flow should be as follows. User's browser connects to his proxy and his proxy (*that proxy*) should forward the request to Squid3 which in turn connects to the target.

User---> User's proxy ---> Squid3 ---> Internet

The user should configure his proxy to use Squid3, unless you are using firewall to route HTTP traffic via Squid3.

Comment: Hi, Sameer!

While my user's client computer is inside LAN I supervise, his proxy is outside the LAN. It's just the ordinary proxy, like those you can find in free proxy lists.

So, the desired chart of data flow is like this:
`User -> Squid3 -> Proxy  -> Web-site`


But now really data go like this:
`User -> Squid3 -> Web-site`